# How to stop embedded Youtube videos

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, youtube

I'm making a site for a friend and it has several youtube music videos embedded in it. I'm trying to make the youtube videos stop when the div with the class "showvm" is clicked. I've had a look around at similar topics but still can't figure out how to make them stop.
The code for the Videos is below and heres a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aw555000/267FR/2/).

```
<div class="videoscreen">
<div class="video"><iframe width="480" height="270" src="http://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/jGec7pMBvsk?rel=0&iv_load_policy=3&wmode=transparent" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
<div class="video"><iframe width="480" height="270" src="http://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/7cT7FAkQZ2Q?rel=0&iv_load_policy=3&wmode=transparent" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
<div class="video"><iframe width="480" height="270" src="http://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/JE-FUZPic2E?rel=0&iv_load_policy=3&wmode=transparent" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
<div class="video"><iframe width="480" height="270" src="http://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/DWpl2CaCnVA?rel=0&iv_load_policy=3&wmode=transparent" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
<div class="video"><iframe width="480" height="270" src="http://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/yebXjZA60OQ?rel=0&iv_load_policy=3&wmode=transparent" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
<div class="video"><iframe width="480" height="270" src="http://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/QuOu31aIiKY?rel=0&iv_load_policy=3&wmode=transparent" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
<div class="video"><iframe width="480" height="270" src="http://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/04FdisNU3vw?rel=0&iv_load_policy=3&wmode=transparent" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
<div class="video"><iframe width="480" height="270" src="http://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/_H7ZG7yk5Wo?rel=0&iv_load_policy=3&wmode=transparent" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
<div class="video"><iframe width="480" height="270" src="http://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/yZvXb38z_R8?rel=0&iv_load_policy=3&wmode=transparent" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
<div class="video"><iframe width="480" height="270" src="http://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/iUtGJtyoIfg?rel=0&iv_load_policy=3&wmode=transparent" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
<div class="video"><iframe width="480" height="270" src="http://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/xF3MC8PWgJE?rel=0&iv_load_policy=3&wmode=transparent" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
<div class="video"><iframe width="480" height="270" src="http://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/akPDKYwIoVk?rel=0&iv_load_policy=3&wmode=transparent" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
</div>
```

Please help. Thanks

Comment: The easiest way to stop an iframe video usually is to remove the iframe src, and add it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
$('#videoscreen iframe').each(function() {

//First get the  iframe URL
var url = $(this).attr('src');

//Then assign the src to null, this then stops the video been playing
$(this).attr('src', '');

// Finally you reasign the URL back to your iframe, so when you hide and load it again you still have the link
$(this).attr('src', url);
});
```

**[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/267FR/3/)**

Comment: Can you explain this a little more? I'm slightly confused as to how to implement this.

Comment: what are you confused about. You need to add the above code in `$('.showvm').click(function(){`

Comment: I added it where you said and it didnt stop the video, however when I change "#videoscreen" to ".video" it worked. many thanks!

Comment: yeah your original markup did not had that id. even created fiddle in answer

Comment: Question: does that seem to impact the performance of the animation? as for me it seems to make the animation really laggy. I'm not complaining just wondering

Answer (score 0):

Use the youtube javascript API: https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference

Once you have it setup, you can load videos by ID (rather than URL), and you can use functions like:

`player.playVideo()` and `player.stopVideo()`

Comment: Please explain how to do this, I've seen this answer on other topics and I'm really confused as to how to implement it

Comment: Read the getting started section of this page: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference, it contains an in depth decent starting point for what you need.